# Get text content from React element stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to get text content from a React element stored in a variable without ref?

There is a functional component, that receives `title` prop, which contains react element:

```
function component({ title }) {
 const content = title.textContent() // Need Something like this
}
```

and this `title` prop might have react node like: `<div>Some Title</div>`. But I'd like to get only content of the node, in a variable before rendering it. Is it possible?

When I console.log `title` variable this is the output, The content I want is inside `props.children` array, so is there a method to get it without traversing through keys:

[image]

Comment: Just check where the content is store by expanding the props in the console, then do title.props.children.attributeThatStoreTheText to get the value.

Answer (score 18):

I've not found a better solution than indeed traversing the object to get the text. In TypeScript:

```js
/**
 * Traverse any props.children to get their combined text content.
 *
 * This does not add whitespace for readability: `<p>Hello <em>world</em>!</p>`
 * yields `Hello world!` as expected, but `<p>Hello</p><p>world</p>` returns
 * `Helloworld`, just like https://mdn.io/Node/textContent does.
 *
 * NOTE: This may be very dependent on the internals of React.
 */
function textContent(elem: React.ReactElement | string): string {
  if (!elem) {
    return '';
  }
  if (typeof elem === 'string') {
    return elem;
  }
  // Debugging for basic content shows that props.children, if any, is either a
  // ReactElement, or a string, or an Array with any combination. Like for
  // `<p>Hello <em>world</em>!</p>`:
  //
  //   $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
  //   type: "p"
  //   props:
  //     children:
  //       - "Hello "
  //       - $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
  //         type: "em"
  //         props:
  //           children: "world"
  //       - "!"
  const children = elem.props && elem.props.children;
  if (children instanceof Array) {
    return children.map(textContent).join('');
  }
  return textContent(children);
}
```

I don't like it at all, and hope there's a better solution.

Comment: Just a quick note that this method doesn't handle arrays.
This can be easily achieved by adding a 2nd check:

`if (Array.isArray(elem)) return elem.map((e) => getJSXTextContent(e)).join('');`

Comment: Be happy with what you made, i'm using it without any complaints

Comment: @André nice to know that React's internals apparently have not changed/broken this in the past two years.

Comment: I implemented it yesterday, in a React 18 app so, looks like it

Comment: +1 for your answer, but your code doesn't work for me.
 I'm testing this on complex components - like predesigned progress-bar with label next to it, and other library controls. And I'm always getting empty string. However, for simple staff like basic divs and spans it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

use https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities

```
import Children from 'react-children-utilities'


const MyComponent = ({ children }) => Children.onlyText(children)
```

from https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9255

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer (and seemingly better) way to do this now:

```
// typescript
const nodeToString = (node: ReactNode) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const root = createRoot(div);
  flushSync(() => root.render(node));
  return div.innerText; // or innerHTML or textContent
};
```

This is the [recommended replacement for `renderToString` from `react-dom/server`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code). Can't comment on its performance vs. `renderToString` or the custom solutions in the other answers here, but this seems more robust.

**One gotcha** is React doesn't like it if you call `flushSync` within a render template or even a `useEffect` (see [an example here](https://x.com/ryanflorence/status/1722358755499913582?s=20) of how `flushSync` is intended to be used), and you'll get lots of console errors.

Ideally, you'd put it in a callback that only runs as a result of a user action. But if you can't do that, here's an example of a work-around:

```
function someComponent({ children }) {
  const [label, setLabel] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // run outside of react lifecycle
    window.setTimeout(() => setLabel(nodeToString(children)));
  }, [content]);

  return <div aria-label={label}>{children}</div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Arjan for the effort and solution, but I have changed something in the component, to get the title in string format.
Now I have added another props to the component: `renderTitle` which is a function to render custom react title.

So now I am passing title as string:

```
<Component
  title="Some content"
  renderTitle={(title) => <div>{title}</div> }
/>
```

and inside component:

```
  <div>{renderTitle ? renderTitle(title) : title}</div>
```

With this implementation, I can use title as string to do what I want inside the component, while also supporting custom title render.