# How to get innerText of div with input value in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to get div innerText along with the input values of that div.
For example:

`<div> My name is Shubham, I work for <input type="text"/> for the last 5 years.</div>`

All I want to get all the texts of that div like:

> My name is Shubham, I work for Microsoft for the last 5 years.

I tried with e.currentTarget.innerHTML but I was not getting desired result.
Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

```
<div
  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHTML)}
  className="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500"
>
  My name is Shubham, I work for <input type="text"/> for the last 5 years.
</div>
```

Comment: Provide full code, please.

Comment: I found a nice solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141123/get-text-content-from-react-element-stored-in-a-variable

Answer (score 2):

Just use `React.useRef` (function component) or `React.createRef` (Class component)

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  // log on second render
  // My name is Shubham, I work for  for the last 5 years.
  console.log(ref.current?.innerText);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      My name is Shubham, I work for <input type="text" /> for the last 5 years.
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not getting input value from this

Comment: Add another ref to the `input` element

Answer (score 1):

To get the inner text of an element in a React component, you can use the ref and innerText properties. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const myElementRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={myElementRef}>This is the inner text.</div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(myElementRef.current.innerText)}>
        Get Inner Text
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: [AI generated posts are not allowed.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: This doesn't result in the behavior OP is looking for. It's a copy/paste of the answer already posted.

Answer (score -2):

```
// give your div an id attribute, lets say x
// <div id="x">Text here/div>

// in JavaScript: 
let divText = document.getElementById("x").innerText
```

Comment: I'm not getting the value of input from this.

Comment: this is not enough to get the results OP is looking for